# sorting vector containing addresses

Tags: c++, vector

I have a struct called Entry that contains two strings and one int:

```
struct Entry
{ 
    string id, name; 
    int age; 
};
```

I have a vector containing a bunch of Entry and another vector contains the address of Entry's in the first vector.

vector 1:

```
vector<Entry> table1
```

vector 2:

```
vector<Entry*> table2
```

I want to be able to sort table2 by the id's of items in table1.

how do i go about doing this?
i tried simply using the sort function.. but thats not working because i think its just sorting by the addresses.. which is not what i want..

Comment: ...because you want to have addresses of Entry in same order. Why you cannot return just &table1[i] since then == table2[i]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a custom comparator to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
std::sort(table2.begin(), table2.end(), [](Entry* a, Entry* b) {
    return a->id < b->id;
});
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f11452f656c629ab)

If for your `Entry` class an `operator<` would make sense, it might be a good idea to overload it and reduce the body of the comparator:

```
bool operator<(Entry const& a, Entry const& b) {
    return a.id < b.id;
}
// …
std::sort(table2.begin(), table2.end(), [](Entry* a, Entry* b) { return *a < *b; });
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d25467e84af66e2)